# Custom UITableViewCell with drop-down in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa, xib

I want to implement custom `UITableViewCell` with XIB. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNF3M.jpg) is the drawing. The button on the right side of the *main view* shows/hides *additional view*. I have two questions:

1. How can I hide the *additional view*? I think that one possibility would be to set height in the frame of additional UIView to zero. Are there any better options?
2. The buttons in *additional view* (in this case 1-5) should appear dynamically. There are two sets of data: one for the left side (buttons 1-3) and other one for the right side (buttons 4-5). The height for the left buttons is fixed, let's say 70px each. The height of the buttons on the right side should be adjusted so that total height of right side buttons is the same as total height on left side. How can the buttons be added dynamically considering these rules?

The buttons will be added during runtime. For example there are two arrays:

`var leftButtons:[String] = ["button1label", “button2label“, "button3label"]`

`var rightButtons:[String] = ["button4label", "button5label"]`.

Let's say I add `"button6label"` to `leftButtons` later on *during runtime*. The size for the `leftView`/`rightView` as well as the size for the buttons inside these views should be adjusted. Again, height of each button on the left-hand size is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should add `ContainerView` view on your custom UITableViewCell, Now add constraints on the `ContainerView` - `leading , trailing,  top & bottom to superView` with `priority 999` for all constraints`.

Now you should add two view on `ContainerView`, one is `mainView` and other is `additionView`.

and add constraints on the `mainView` - leading to superView, top to superView, trailing to superView and height constraint (let say 70).

now add `textfield` and `show/hide button` in side the mainView and apply constraints on `textField` and `show/hide button`.

**textField constraints** - `leading to superView`, `top to superView`, `bottom to superView` and `Horizontal spacing between textField & show/hide button`.

**show/hide button constraints** - `top to superView`, `bottom to superView`, `trailing to superView` and width constraints.

Here `mainView` is configured properly. So now let's configure `additionView`

you should add two new view in `additionView`, one is `leftView` and other is `rightView` & `add constraints` on the `leftView & rightView`.

**leftView constraints** - `leading to superView`, `top to superView`, `bottom to superView` , `Horizontal spacing between leftView & rightView`, 
`equal width and width constraints of leftView to rightView`.

**rightView constraints** - `trailing to superView`, `top to superView`&`bottom to superView`
Here your `Interface Builder Designing completed` so now we need to manage the buttons on left and right View at runtime. to do this you must make a custome classs is called `VerticalContainerView` that will manage the buttons vertical distribution.

I have created the **VerticalContainerView** using the [KVConstraintExtensionsMaster](https://github.com/keshavvishwkarma/KVConstraintExtensionsMaster)  library to apply constraints that I have implemented.

Put below code in `VerticalContainerView.h` header file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface VerticalContainerView : UIView
-(void)configureButtonsbyNames:(NSArray<__kindof NSString *>*)names isDistribuated:(BOOL)isDistributed;
@end
```

Put below code in `VerticalContainerView.m` file

```
#import "VerticalContainerView.h"
#import "KVConstraintExtensionsMaster.h"

@implementation VerticalContainerView

-(void)configureButtonsbyNames:(NSArray<__kindof NSString *>*)names isDistribuated:(BOOL)isDistributed
{
    /* Just Two steps to Apply\Add constraints by programatically */
    /* Step 1 create & configure the view hierarchy for constraint first. */
    /* Step 2 Apply the constraints */

    CGFloat space  = 0.0;
    CGFloat height = 70.0;

    UIButton *previousContentButton = nil;
    NSInteger count  = names.count;

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        UIButton *contentButton = [UIButton prepareNewViewForAutoLayout];
        if (i&1) {
            [contentButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        }else{
            [contentButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
        }

        [contentButton setTag:i];
        [contentButton setTitle:names[i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self addSubview:contentButton];

        [contentButton applyLeadingAndTrailingPinConstraintToSuperviewWithPadding:space];

        if (!isDistributed) {
            [contentButton applyHeightConstraint:height];
        }

        if (i == 0) // for first
        {
            [contentButton applyTopPinConstraintToSuperviewWithPadding:space];
        }
        else if (i == count-1) // for last
        {
            if (isDistributed) {
                [previousContentButton applyConstraintFromSiblingViewAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight toAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight ofView:contentButton spacing:space];
            }

            [previousContentButton applyConstraintFromSiblingViewAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom toAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop ofView:contentButton spacing:space];
            [contentButton applyBottomPinConstraintToSuperviewWithPadding:space];
        }
        else
        {
            if (isDistributed) {
                [previousContentButton applyConstraintFromSiblingViewAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight toAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight ofView:contentButton spacing:space];
            }

            [previousContentButton applyConstraintFromSiblingViewAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom toAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop ofView:contentButton spacing:space];
        }

        previousContentButton = contentButton;
    }

}

@end
```

Now create a custom Cell is called `CustomCell` & put below code in `CustomCell.h` header file

```
#import "VerticalContainerView.h"

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet VerticalContainerView *leftVerticalContainerView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet VerticalContainerView *rightVerticalContainerView;
@end
```

Put below code in `CustomCell.m` file.

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell

-(void)prepareForReuse
{
    // here you have to remove the all the buttons from left and right veiw becuase
    // Every cell can have distinct number buttons on left and right view.

    for (UIView *subView in self.leftVerticalContainerView.subviews) {
        [subView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    for (UIView *subView in self.leftVerticalContainerView.subviews) {
        [subView removeFromSuperview];
    }

    [super prepareForReuse];

}

@end
```

Now changes `UITableViewCell Class` by our CustomCell with the help of `Identity inspector editor` of `Interface Builder`

Also changes `left and right View Class` by our `VerticalContainerView` with the help of `Identity inspector editor` of `Interface Builder`

Now connect the `IBOutlet` of our CusromCell for `leftVerticalContainerView & rightVerticalContainerView`

Put the below code in the viewDidLoad method ofyour ViewController is:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
/* any estimated height but must be more than 2, but it should be more estimated */
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 210.0;
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;

// if you created cell from `.xib` is called CustomCell.xib,then you have to register that cell with table.
//    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil];
//    [tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"YouCellIdentifier"];
```

Now implement `UITableView DataSource` in your ViewController

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section{
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.row%2 == 0) {
        // this is fixed height constraints
        [cell.leftVerticalContainerView configureButtonsbyNames:@[@"button1",@"button2",@"button3"] isDistributed:NO];
        // this is distributed height constraints according to left view
        [cell.rightVerticalContainerView configureButtonsbyNames:@[@"button4",@"button5"] isDistributed:YES];
    }
    else{
        // this is fixed height constraints
        [cell.leftVerticalContainerView configureButtonsbyNames:@[@"button1",@"button2",@"button3",@"button4",@"button5"] isDistributed:NO];

        // this is isDistribuated height constraints according to left view
        [cell.rightVerticalContainerView configureButtonsbyNames:@[@"button6",@"button7",@"button8"] isDistributed:YES];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I edited the question. Maybe it was not clear, but the buttons can be added _during runtime_ as well. So in this case the method you described will not work.

Comment: I have provided general approach to add constraint  but It's up to you,  how are you dealing with constrain ?

Comment: I have also updated my answer according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `UITableViewCell`s with Automatic Height.
This allows you to use constraints to determine the cell's height.

To get this working:

- Add the following lines to turn on Automatic Height:

  `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
  `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160.0` // An approximate cell height.
- Use constraints to make the cell's content *push outwards* so that the content determines the cell height.
- Add a height constraint to the additional view with an `IBOutlet` in code. Set this constraint's `constant` property to `0`, and set the `.hidden` property of additional view to `true` to hide the additional view.
- For a nicer opening/closing, change the constraints `constant` property inside a `UIView` animation block.

Comment: As I wrote in the comment for the answer below, I edited the question. The buttons should be added _during runtime_ as well. What to do in such situation?

Comment: Well you can add the additional view, buttons, and their constraints programatically.